# Add missing dates to pandas dataframe with zeros as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, group-by

Very standard task: data can have multiple events on a given date or no events. I to take these events, enrich the in the data missing dates in given range and  zero values, so later I can a count by date and plot the data.

I'm new to pandas and have followed [reindex to add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326546/reindex-to-add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe) and [pandas fill missing dates in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231496/pandas-fill-missing-dates-in-time-series). Although it was accepted by a number of stackoverflow readers, it does not work for me, as it Nullifies already existing 'quantity' column values:

```
CODE: 
    # (items_per_day is coming from DB)
    date_now = datetime.now().date()
    date_period = date_now-timedelta(weeks=1)

    data = list(items_per_day)
    print('data: ', data)

    idx = pd.period_range(date_period, date_now)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print('df: ', df)

    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
    print('df index: ', df)

    df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    print('df: ', df)

OUTPUT:

data:  [{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 17), 'quantity': 1}, {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 18), 'quantity': 2}, {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 19), 'quantity': 3}]

df:           date  quantity
0  2022-08-17         1
1  2022-08-18         2
2  2022-08-19         3

df index:                                       date  quantity
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  2022-08-17         1
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001  2022-08-18         2
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002  2022-08-19         3

df:             date  quantity
2022-08-13    0         0
2022-08-14    0         0
2022-08-15    0         0
2022-08-16    0         0
2022-08-17    0         0
2022-08-18    0         0
2022-08-19    0         0
2022-08-20    0         0
```

It looks like that reindex losses the data with or without 'fill_value' param! Although [Add missing dates pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554380/add-missing-dates-pandas-dataframe) solution based on different principal works:

```
CODE:
    date_now = datetime.now().date()
    date_period = date_now-timedelta(weeks=1)

    data = list(items_per_day)
    print('data: ', data)

    idx = pd.period_range(date_period, date_now)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print('df: ', df)

    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

    dates = pd.date_range(start=date_period, freq='D', periods=7)
    df = df.set_index('date').reindex(dates.normalize().rename('date')).reset_index()
    df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].fillna(0)
    print('df: ', df)

OUTPUT:
data:  [{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 17), 'quantity': 1}, {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 18), 'quantity': 2}, {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 19), 'quantity': 3}]

df:           date  quantity
0  2022-08-17         1
1  2022-08-18         2
2  2022-08-19         3

df:     date  quantity
0 2022-08-13       0.0
1 2022-08-14       0.0
2 2022-08-15       0.0
3 2022-08-16       0.0
4 2022-08-17       1.0
5 2022-08-18       2.0
6 2022-08-19       3.0
```

I would like to understand why the first solution does not work in my case (it obviously worked for a number of people who voted to it!). What is the root cause of the failure in my case?

Comment: In your first approach, the `idx` is `PeriodIndex`. Do you mean `idx = pd.date_range(date_now - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1), date_now)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first approach, you are reindexing a `DatetimeIndex` with a `PeriodIndex`(created by period_range), use `date_range` instead of `period_range` works:

```
idx = pd.date_range(date_period, date_now)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)

df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
#                  date  quantity
#2022-08-13           0         0
#2022-08-14           0         0
#2022-08-15           0         0
#2022-08-16           0         0
#2022-08-17  2022-08-17         1
#2022-08-18  2022-08-18         2
#2022-08-19  2022-08-19         3
#2022-08-20           0         0
```